# TensorFlow: AttributeError when calling TensorFlow's IO functions; why are they missing?

Tags: python, tensorflow, import, module

I use TensorFlow 1.12.0 with Python 3.5. When I call `tf.io.decode_jpg()` (or any function from `tf.io`), I get the following error: `AttributeError: module 'tensorflow._api.v1.io' has no attribute 'decode_***'`.

I import TensorFlow as following:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
```

I also tried importing the `io` module directly, but to no avail. I call the function as follows:

```py
rgb = tf.io.decode_image(tf.read_file(DIR_DATASET + sample_name + ".jpg"))
```

Comment: here is the link to tf 1.12 [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.12/api_docs/python/tf/io) 
The functions you refer to seem to be available with 1.13, whose documentation is [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/io)

Comment: Ah, they're still located in ```tf.image``` in 1.12. Thanks!